# Cómo agregar elementos a propiedad (array) de un item creado

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Amig@s,

Mi duda es la siguiente: al momento de crear un objeto tipo Usuario quiero añadir id que corresponden a los roles que puede tener dicho usuario.
El problema pasa que no he podido dar en el clavo para agregar dichos ids a mi array de tipo roles que es una propiedad de mi objeto Usuario.

Actualmente mi estructura es la siguiente

**Schema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: String,
    email: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true
    },
    roles: [String]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

**API**

```
router.post('/user/item', (req, res) => {
        var user = new User();
        user.username = req.body.username;
        user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password);
        user.email = req.body.email;
        //user.update({ _id:1 }, { $addToSet: { roles: { $each: req.body.roles }}})

        user.save().then(() => {
            res.json({ success: true, message: 'Cuenta creada' });
        }, (err) => {
            res.json({ success: false, message: `error: ${err}` });
        });
    });
```

Si se percatan, en la línea comentada esta lo que necesito hacer, pero debido a que es un update y aun no tengo el `_id` creado por Mongo no entiendo como proceder con la insersión de items al arreglo de roles.

Había pensado en realizar la actualización una vez se insertará el objeto en la BD para de esta forma obtener el **_id** pero no sé que tan efectivo sea esto, a mi personalmente no me convence mucho

Como siempre, cualquier información se agradece :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no entiendo mal, deseas agregar un rol al usuario al momento de crear al usuario. Entiendo que los roles ya están definidos en la base de datos en una colección, y que tienes un modelo para `Rol`.

Si es así, entonces debes crear una referencia a tu modelo `Rol` en el modelo `User`.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea agregar el `_id` de uno o varios documentos de la colección `roles` durante la creación de un documento de la colección `users`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para lograr el objetivo debemos modificar el Modelo de Mongoose para que se vea de la siguiente manera:

**User Model** (ES5)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ // <= PODEMOS USAR CONST, EL ESQUEMA NO VARIA
    username: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: String,
    email: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true
    },
    roles: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Rol'
    }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Luego, para insertar los roles del usuario al momento de crearlos, hacemos lo siguiente:

**Router** (ES5)

```
router.post('/user/item', (req, res) => {
    let user = new User(); // <= Evitemos usar 'var'
    user.username = req.body.username;
    user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password);
    user.email = req.body.email;
    user.roles = req.body.roles; // <= Este campo contiene un array con los id correspondientes
    user.save().then(() => {
        res.json({ success: true, message: 'Cuenta creada' });
    }, (err) => {
        res.json({ success: false, message: `error: ${err}` });
    });
});
```

De esta manera ya tienes en el campo `roles` los valores `_id` de los documentos correspondientes a los roles del usuario.

Suponiendo que deseamos agregar dos `_id`, entonces el atributo `req.body.roles` podría verse de la siguiente forma:

```
["5c3d2b3502d0a9467037ede5","5c3d2b4702d0a9467037ede7"]
```

Donde cada "string" corresponde a un rol.

**SUGERENCIA**

Si en tu `body` vas a pasar solamente los campos requeridos por el modelo `User`, en vez de hacer un repetitivo:

```
let user = new User();
user.username = req.body.username;
user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password);
user.email = req.body.email;
user.roles = req.body.roles;
```

podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
let user = new User(req.body);
user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password);
```

y así en una sola línea tenemos el mismo resultado.

Otra sugerencia: no uses `hashSync()`, es preferible el método asíncrono `hash()`.

Y por último, realiza el hash del password usando un `prehook`, eso lo defines en el esquema.

Espero que la respuesta sea satisfactoria.

Comment: Excelentísima respuesta; además me aclaraste un tema que tenía entre ceja y ceja al indicarme que podía pasar como parámetro el `req.body` al **User** directamente. Gracias totales!